# Could identify this bag #2, 540R6, year 2015 135149 - lots of Dark Grey and Tan

Tags: set-identification

It looks like it is from a Star Wars set, but I'm still looking where it came from, thanks
[image: lots of Dark Grey and Tan]

[image: lots of Dark Grey and Tan]

[image: lots of Dark Grey and Tan]

[image: lots of Dark Grey and Tan]

Comment: The codes only identify the bag itself, not the contents. With a clear picture (or three), you are almost definitely going to get a good answer.

Comment: Sorry im new in this, im adding some pics hopefully can help, thanks

Comment: Once it's opened again, I'll answer with my justification for 21119-1 The Dungeon (based on Light Bluish Gray Plate 4 x 10, Tan Brick 2 x 8, Tan Brick 2 x 4).

Comment: @RSchulz : I concur - I find the same.

Answer (score 7):

According to BrickLink, the only set with all of Light Bluish Gray Plate 4 x 10, Tan Brick 2 x 8, Tan Brick 2 x 4 is 21119-1 [The Dungeon](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=21119-1)

[image: Dungeon]